# php regex change youtube links to videos

Tags: php, regex, youtube

I have functions that change links into clickable links and one that changes youtube links into embedded videos.

However, if you post a youtube video first then a regular link, all links turn into youtube videos.

How can I edit my functions to only change youtube links into embedded videos and ignore regular links?

```
function convertLinks($Link) {
    $Link = preg_replace(
            "#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#",
            "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>",
            $Link);
    $Link = preg_replace(
            "#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r< ]*)#",
            "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>",
            $Link);
    return $Link;
}
function convertYouTube($Link) {
    if (preg_match(
            '%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i',
            $Link,
            $match)) {
        $video_id = $match[1];
        $Link = htmlspecialchars_decode(
                preg_replace(
                        "#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#",
                        "\\1<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$video_id\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
                        $Link));
    }
    return $Link;
}
function convertMessages($Comment) {

    $Comment = convertYouTube($Comment);
    $Comment = convertLinks($Comment);

    return $Comment;
}
```

Comment: Start by posting the format oft the: originial link, the clickables one, and the embeded one... that will help :)

Comment: The links are just any regular link, http://www.google.com. The ConvertMessages() function just takes an entire message and converts any links it finds. So it could be exactly this post and it will make the google link clickable.

Comment: Please could you show the code where you call `convertMessages()`?

Comment: Isn't much to show:
<div class=\"message-text\">".convertMessages($Comment)."</div>

Comment: The problem is in `convertYouTube` -> here you do check first (`preg_match`) for youtube links, but then following (`preg_replace`) you still replace all links. What you need to do is modify the `preg_replace` so that it only affects youtube URLs.. Quick and dirty: Change the regex in the `preg_replace` something like this: `"#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]*youtu\.?be[\w]*+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#"` (would still _greedily_ replace all other links containing youtube.. eg `http://domain.tld/my-blog-about-youtube-foo-bar`

Comment: You should probably start by checking for an occurrence of `youtube.com` or `youtu.be` etc before bothering to process that URL

Answer (score 0):

I think I see where ukautz is coming from; you're finding certain youtube-only link text in your preg_match, yet in your preg_replace your regex doesn't care about youtube-specific text. If you were somehow able to isolate out the links before preg_matching them, this should solve the problem; however an easier solution might be to just combine your preg_match regex with your preg_replace regex.